# Are there any similar sites to code.gouv.fr with a search engine that supports tags?

Tags: webapp-rec, search

I am looking for a tool similar to code.gouv.fr that allows users to find repositories via a search engine that works with tags.

code.gouv.fr will only return an answer if the exact description as written on the repository is written in the search engine. For example, the tsfaker program will appear if one writes "tabular fake data" but not "tabular data". I am looking for a site with a more evolved search engine that can "guess" answers thanks to tags and not just word for word descriptions.

I am not looking for a tool that hosts repositories such as github or gitlab, but a tool that leads back to gitlab repositories once the search has been completed (basically the same as code.gouv.fr but with a more efficient search engine that supports tags).

Does anyone know whether this exists ?

Many thanks